# Schedule automatic updates - not from Google Play?

Tags: updates, apk, application-autoupdate

I don't use Google Play with my Android-based phone; mostly I use APKPure and its app.

However, I do want to be able to schedule periodic updates of all apps (or of some apps) - instead of me having to manually approve app update downloads and/op individual app update installation. It could be via APKPure or anywhere else that's sort of respectable, I don't mind - but it can't require something like logging into to Google/Facebook/etc.

Is this achievable?

Notes:

- In case it matters - I use Xiaomi RedMi 3s, Android 6.0.1, MIUI 9.2.2.
- I'd rather not have to root my device in order to do this. If you think I must, please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [APK updater](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-apkupdater-t3444517) , also available on F-droid ( if you add  [Izzy's repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/repo)) and
is meant for cases like yours where you are not using Play store.

> Update sources
>   At the moment four sources are supported:
>
> - APKMirror
> - Google Play
> - APKPure
> - Uptodown

You can schedule daily or weekly updates, time of update and update on startup

**Edit:** It requires root permissions to update all. You can download the updates for apps you want to update by *ignore* others, followed by clicking the blue circle icon and install them.

You would need to give permissions to install from external sources. In screenshot below , I updated a single app "aSpotcat" which shows "installed" and other apps showing "Install"

Not an ideal solution for auto updates since it requires manual intervention if device is not rooted

[image]

Comment: I just searched on F-Droid using the app and it doesn't seem to be available... weird. But I did get it from the GitHub repo. Also - APKUpdater's settings say that automatic updates require root privileges.

Comment: Finally - this app doesn't even seem to have a "install all updates" button, nor an "install single update" button. Will it actually install them anytime?

Comment: For me, after I click the blue button it just has a list of updates, and doesn't seem to install them.